# Need help in extracting specific paragraph text and images from whole blog page html

Tags: php, html, parsing, blogs

I need help in html parsing. Before posting question here I tried to find this answer but couldn't find. I have stored complete html of blog page in a database table. Now I want to extract text and images from that html. BUT I have to extract only paragraph specific text and images from the whole html.

See example below, it has lot of code tags in it. It has three paragraphs. I have to extract text and images only from paragraph 2 which is relevant to my requirement. (I have keyword and I can search that keyword and in this way I can identify that I need to extract this paragraph.)

How can I extract specific paragraph text and images from any blog. I have keyword to search in html i.e. Keyword = PRODUCT ABC. I am using php.

```
<html>
<!-- Javascript: tag come here --->
<!-- Head: tag come here --->
<!-- Meta: tag come here --->
<!-- Title: tag come here --->
<!-- Links: tag come here --->
<!-- Javascript: tag come here --->

<body>

<!-- Lot of other code come here about links, javascript, headings etc -->
<!-- DIV: tag come here --->

<p> "PARAGRAPH 1, This paragraph contain only some text." </p>
<!-- Script: tag come here --->

<p> PARAGRAPH 2, It has some information about PRODUCT ABC...</p>
<img /> <!-- some images come here related to this paragraph.-->
<img /> <!-- some images come here related to this paragraph.-->
<img /> <!-- some images come here related to this paragraph.-->
<!-- Script: tag come here --->

<p> PARAGRAPH 3, This paragraph contain only some text. </p>
<img /> <!-- some images come here related to this paragraph.-->
<!-- Links: tag come here --->
<!-- Javascript: tag come here --->

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use this PHP based dom parser written by sourceforge.ref:http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I am already using it but it couldn't help me for a specific paragraph text and related images. It bring all text and images for whole page level. All text and all images spoil my required results. Do you know how can we get specific paragraph text and images?

Comment: Why dont you first extract that specific paragraph using dom parser and store in a variable , then call find on the sample variable to extract images or any elements which you need. `$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

$par=$html->find('p[id=hello]') ;
foreach($par->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dreamwiever. Although, this is the html forum. :P

Use this code:

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/'); $par=$html->find('p[id=hello]') ; foreach($par->find('img') as $element) echo $element->src . '
'

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a simple `tag` to extract , you can use `regex`

simply :

```
$html = "<html><head></head><body><div>sometext</div><div><p>myPtag</p></div><div> some other text</div></body></html>";

preg_match('/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/',$html,$getTheP);

//and simply call what you want from extraction 
var_dump($getTheP);
```

**and** still , if you want something to be match in your `<p>` tag, you
 can simple make a new path to get what you want :

for example , we want the `<p>` that contain `somestring`

```
preg_match('/<p>(.*?)somestring<\/p>',$html,$matchesWithSomeString);

var_dump ( $matchesWithSomeString )
```

;